# Remove files in given folder but leave files in subfolders

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I think this should be rather simple but I want to delete all the files that are stated in for example: `C:\TEST` but I want to leave the files that are located in subdirectories of this  folder. For example files in the folder: `C:\TEST\Backup` should not be deleted.

When using the following batch command all the files get deleted including those located in sub directories but it leaves the folder:

```
DEL /S C:\TEST\ /q
```

Does anyone know the command that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
DEL /Q C:\TEST\*.*
```

It will delete all files in C:\TEST. 
Wildcard `*.*` selects only files.

If you need a prompt before deleting a file remove `/Q` from the command.

Syntax:

```
DEL|ERASE [options] [/A:file_attributes] files_to_delete
```

Options:

```
  /P  Give a Yes/No Prompt before deleting. 
  /F  Ignore read-only setting and delete anyway (FORCE) 
  /S  Delete from all Subfolders (DELTREE)
  /Q  Quiet mode, do not give a Yes/No Prompt before deleting.

  /A  Select files to delete based on file_attributes
        file_attributes:
          R  Read-only    -R  NOT Read-only
          A  Archive      -A  NOT Archive
          S  System       -S  NOT System
          H  Hidden       -H  NOT Hidden
          I  Not content indexed  -I  content indexed files
          L  Reparse points       -L  NOT Reparse points

          X  No scrub file attribute  -X  Scrub file attribute   (Windows 8+)
          V  Integrity attribute      -V  NO Integrity attribute (Windows 8+)
```

[Source](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)